# Conversion of breakOut - use iterator or view?

Tags: scala, collections, scala-2.13

[Scala 2.13 migration guide](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/collections-migration-213.html) contains a note regarding how to port `collection.breakOut`:

> `collection.breakOut` no longer exists, use `.view` and `.to(Collection)` instead.

and few paragraphs below in a overview table there is:

> | Description | Old Code | New Code | Automatic Migration Rule |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | `collection.breakOut` no longer exists | `val xs: List[Int]` `= ys.map(f)` `(collection.breakOut)` | `val xs =` `ys.iterator.map(f).to(List)` | `Collection213Upgrade` |

The `scala-collection-migration` rewrite rule uses `.iterator`. What is the difference between the two? Is there a reason to prefer one to the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When used like that there is no real difference.

A `View` can be reused while an `Iterator` must be discarded after it's been used once.

```
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)

val view = list.view
val viewPlus1 = view.map(_ + 1).toList
view.foreach(println) // works as expected

val it = list.iterator
val itPlus1 = it.map(_ + 1).toList
it.foreach(println) // undefined behavior
```

In its simplest form a `View[A]` is a wrapper around a function `() => Iterator[A]`, so all its methods can create a fresh `Iterator[A]` and delegate to the appropriate method on that iterator.